# Web scraping program for loop returns nothing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I developed this simple web scraping program to scrape newegg.com. I made a for loop to print out the name of the product, price, and shipping cost.

However, when I run the for loop it doesn't print out anything and does not give me any error. Before I write the for loop (commented items) I have ran those lines (commented items) and it prints the details only for one of the products.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

#prod = soup.find('a', class_='item-title').text
#price = soup.find('li', class_='price-current').text.strip()
#ship = soup.find('li', class_='price-ship').text.strip()
#print(prod.strip())
#print(price.strip())
#print(ship)

for info in soup.find_all('div', class_='item-container  '):
    prod = soup.find('a', class_='item-title').text
    price = soup.find('li', class_='price-current').text.strip()
    ship = soup.find('li', class_='price-ship').text.strip()
    print(prod.strip())
    #price.splitlines()[3].replace('\xa0', '')
    print(price.strip())
    print(ship)
```

Comment: for starters, you had an extra space in `class_='item-container  '`. change that to `class_='item-container '` But I'm thinking this page is dynamic so you'll need to do some extra work to get the data0

Comment: @chitown88 is correct in pointing out the typo that prevented you from entering the loop. But the loop is also constructed incorrectly, as it repeats the same data for each `div` that your `find_all` captures.

Comment: my fault. it isn't dynamic. you never use info when you iterate (as stated in the solutions below)

Comment: @ Rick, if the answer solves your problem you should mark it as accepted

Answer (score -2, accepted):

@Rick you mistakenly added extra space in `for info in soup.find_all('div', class_='item-container  '):` this line after attribute value 
check below code it will work as you expected

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for info in soup.find_all('div', class_='item-container '):
    prod = soup.find('a', class_='item-title').text
    price = soup.find('li', class_='price-current').text.strip()
    ship = soup.find('li', class_='price-ship').text.strip()
    print(prod.strip())
    print(price.strip())
    print(ship)
```

hope this solve your problem...

Comment: Can you help me with something else? Each time the code runs the for loop it is supposed to choose a new product on Newegg each time. However, it prints the same info for one product every time. How can I fix this?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @Rick: Your error (that it always prints the same item) comes from not using `info` in the code below `for info in soup.....:`. Because you then use `soup.find` instead of `info.find`, it will just keep looking for the first occurrence of e.g.  `soup.find('a', class_='item-title')`. If you use `info.find(....)` it will use the next `<div>` element every loop of the for-loop.

Comment: @Rick see the answers by @Niels Henkens and @Loss of human identity for single page, for all 8 pages  increase Page count `Page-1` upto 8 in this link `https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102/Page-1?PageSize=36&order=BESTMATCH` and iterate in same for loop

Answer (score 2):

Besides the 'space' typo and the indentation, you didn't actually use `info` in your for loop. This will just keep printing the first item. Use `info` in your for loop where you had `soup`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for info in soup.find_all('div', class_='item-container'):
    prod = info.find('a', class_='item-title').text.strip()
    price = info.find('li', class_='price-current').text.strip().splitlines()[1].replace(u'\xa0', '')
    if  u'$' not in price:
        price = info.find('li', class_='price-current').text.strip().splitlines()[0].replace(u'\xa0', '')
    ship = info.find('li', class_='price-ship').text.strip()
    print(prod)
    print(price)
    print(ship)
```

Because your code is not using `info` in the code below `for info in soup.....:` but `soup.find(..)`, it will just keep looking for the first occurrence of e.g.  `soup.find('a', class_='item-title')`. If you use `info.find(....)` it will use the next `<div>` element every loop of the for-loop.

**Edit:**
I also found that the price is not always the second item when you use `.splitlines()`, sometimes it's the first. I therefor added a check to see if the item contained the '$' sign. If not, it used the first list item.

Comment: Can you help me to understand the .splitlines()[1]. More specifically the '[1]'.

Comment: .splitlines() creates a list, where the text is split into different items of the list. The [1] is the index for this list, meaning that it takes the second item of the list ([0] is the first item). In most cases, the second item of splitlines() contains the actual price.

Answer (score 2):

Write less code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102').text    
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for info in soup.find_all('div', class_='item-container '):
    print(info.find('a', class_='item-title').text)
    print(info.find('li', class_='price-current').text.strip())        
    print(info.find('li', class_='price-ship').text.strip())
```